# Why did my question asking for an alternative to some pre-built components get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I recently became aware of pre-built Objective-C classes (iRate, Appirator, etc.)  that you can copy and paste into your app that will enable it to display a "please rate this app" dialogue box. As a Swift developer, I don't know Objective-C, so I asked if there were similar pre-built solutions for Swift.

Within 10 minutes, I had 4 down votes. What did I do wrong? This is by no means an attempt to blame the community, appeal the decisions, or any of that. I just want to get some guidance on what I did.

Comment: It looks like you were asking for an external resource (e.g. library, plugin, etc.). Such questions are not allowed on SO.

Comment: Can you link the question? Even if you removed it, 10K users can see it and make their answers specific.

Comment: If someone will ask "Are lambda functions in c++ and how to use them?" you should close his question too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't read (or at least follow) the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Asking for off-site resources or tools is off-topic for SO. I guess you have equal as many close votes on your question.